# How to install Postgresql 9.3 instead of default 9.4 in Ubuntu 14.10?

Tags: apt, 14.10, postgresql

I'm on Utopic Unicorn and I need to install Postgresql 9.3 server and client.
When I try to autocomplete `sudo apt-get install postgres`, I see only 9.4 packages:

```
postgresql                          postgresql-autodoc
postgresql-9.4                      postgresql-client
postgresql-9.4-asn1oid              postgresql-client-9.4
postgresql-9.4-dbg                  postgresql-client-common
postgresql-9.4-debversion           postgresql-common
postgresql-9.4-ip4r                 postgresql-comparator
postgresql-9.4-orafce               postgresql-contrib
postgresql-9.4-pgespresso           postgresql-contrib-9.4
postgresql-9.4-pgextwlist           postgresql-doc
postgresql-9.4-pgfincore            postgresql-doc-9.4
postgresql-9.4-pgmemcache           postgresql-filedump
postgresql-9.4-pgmp                 postgresql-hll
postgresql-9.4-pgpool2              postgresql-plperl-9.4
postgresql-9.4-pgq3                 postgresql-plpython3-9.4
postgresql-9.4-pgrouting            postgresql-plpython-9.4
postgresql-9.4-pgrouting-doc        postgresql-pltcl-9.4
postgresql-9.4-pllua                postgresql-prioritize
postgresql-9.4-plproxy              postgresql-server-dev-9.4
postgresql-9.4-plr                  postgresql-server-dev-all
postgresql-9.4-plsh                 postgres-xc
postgresql-9.4-plv8                 postgres-xc-client
postgresql-9.4-postgis-2.1          postgres-xc-contrib
postgresql-9.4-postgis-2.1-scripts  postgres-xc-dbg
postgresql-9.4-postgis-scripts      postgres-xc-doc
postgresql-9.4-prefix               postgres-xc-plperl
postgresql-9.4-preprepare           postgres-xc-plpython
postgresql-9.4-repmgr               postgres-xc-pltcl
postgresql-9.4-slony1-2             postgres-xc-server-dev
```

How can I install their 9.3 versions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the official postgres PPA / Apt repo. It has packages for all of the supported versions.

See: http://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/

- Create the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list`, and add a line for the repository

  - `deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ utopic-pgdg main`
- Import the repository signing key, and update the package lists

  - `wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | \
    sudo apt-key add -`
  - `sudo apt-get update`

Answer (score 1):

From the [PostgreSQL downloads page](http://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/):

> If the version included in your version of Ubuntu is not the one you
>   want, you can use the PostgreSQL Apt Repository. This repository will
>   integrate with your normal systems and patch management, and provide
>   automatic updates for all supported versions of PostgreSQL throughout
>   the support lifetime of PostgreSQL.
>
> The PostgreSQL apt repository supports LTS versions of Ubuntu, 10.04
>   and 12.04, on amd64 and i386 architectures. While not fully supported,
>   the packages often work on non-LTS versions as well, by using the
>   closest LTS version available.

To add the PostgreSQL repository:

```
sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list <<EOF
deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ utopic-pgdg main
EOF
wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
```

(Yes, despite what it says it looks like they do support 14.10.)